# Why aren't the query results being displayed?

Tags: php, mysql

The below query successfully checks a database for values that equal the users' search (`$upn`).

But when displaying the output at (`$output`) the string only shows `$project` and `$sum` but fails to display `$fname` and `$sname` (which correspond to the `pupil_forename` and `pupil_surname` in the DB).

Why are `$project` & `$sum` values being returned and not `$fname`/`$sname` values?

```
{$query = mysql_query("SELECT pupil_forename AND pupil_surname from pupil WHERE pupil_id =         '$upn'");
$count = mysql_num_rows($query);
if ($count == 0 ) {
    $output = "No Pupil exists.";     
} else{
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        $fname = $row['pupil_forename'];
        $sname = $row['pupil_surname'];

        $sum = ($num1 + $num2 + $num3 + $num4 + $num5 + $num6 + $num7) / 7;
        $query = mysql_query("INSERT into test VALUES ('' , '$upn' , '$project' ,'$sum')");

        $output = '<div>'.$fname.' '.$sname.' was marked '.$sum.' for their submission of     '.$project.'';
    }
```

Comment: `SELECT pupil_forename AND pupil_surname` will not return two result columns, but just one boolean.

Comment: Was the beginning `{` of a try{}catch{} statement or something?

Comment: @aliasm2k: thanks for wanting to improve questions, but you reverted my edit. Please always refresh your screen before doing edits (I'll reapply your changes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to say

```
SELECT pupil_forename, pupil_surname FROM...
```

Saying `AND` triggers a boolean check. It's saying "are each of these values set?" then returning a single true/false instead of the name

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT pupil_forename, pupil_surname FROM pupil WHERE pupil_id = '$upn'
```

instead of your query.

Comment: If you are not going to use prepared queries you should at least note that escaping is a good advice.

Comment: You are right about the escaping, but my answer is not wrong and it is appropriate for the question.